# In the layout package documentation, line 134, why is \inch given as an approximation of 72, instead of it's true value of 72.27?

Tags: layout

I'm sure it's not a bug, just want to understand why.

Comment: Even some respected traditional sources make this simplification; see [Chaundy, et al., *The Printing of Mathematics*, p.2](https://www.gwern.net/docs/design/1954-chaundy-theprintingofmathematics.pdf): "a point being one seventy-second of an inch".  And in the PostScript world, that is now exactly what it is -- a TeX "big point".

Comment: @barbarabeeton in this case, though, it's because the value is stored in a `\count` I've always been amazed a people who managed to do floating point math in TeX. Kent McPherson opted to not do so. They layout doc uses LaTeX's `picture` environment also which requires integer coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an approximate value because the package uses a `\count` to hold the value. It’s a lot easier to work with integer values in TeX than floating point.